# Raise MigrationSchemaMissing("Unable to create the django_migrations table (%s)" % exc)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I have google this question . there plenty of similar problems , but i can't find proper answer.

This is details of error Log :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "d:\django\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "d:\django\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "d:\django\django\core\management\base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "d:\django\django\core\management\base.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "d:\django\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 200, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "d:\django\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 91, in migrate
    self.recorder.ensure_schema()
  File "d:\django\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 57, in ensure_schema
    raise MigrationSchemaMissing("Unable to create the django_migrations table (%s)" % exc)
django.db.migrations.exceptions.MigrationSchemaMissing: Unable to create the django_migrations table ((1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(6) NOT NULL)' at line 1"))
```

This is settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'test',
        'USER': '*****',
        'PASSWORD': '****',
        'HOST': '**.***.***.**',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

This is my models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Test(models.Model):
    _name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="aaa")
    _score = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="DDD")
```

This is my migrations file:0001_initial.py

```
# Generated by Django 2.1.dev20180329192554 on 2018-04-03 04:11

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Test',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('name', models.CharField(default='aaa', max_length=20)),
                ('score', models.CharField(default='DDD', max_length=20)),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

Mysql version : mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.53, for linux2.6 (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Those the pkgs about mysql

[image]

Who has ideas for this problem , Thanks for any help.

Comment: can you share us your migration file? also the mysql package you use.

Comment: @mehrdad-pedramfar  I have add the file to my question.

Comment: @mehrdad-pedramfar  what is mysql package or how can i get mysql package info ? Thank you.

Comment: Read this : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/databases/#mysql-notes

Comment: @mehrdad-pedramfar  there a lot of pkgs about mysql , I have post 
pic about mysql pkgs on my question.

Comment: @Cyrus see ticket https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27054

Comment: @Cyrus Please post your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to Install MySQL /Connector Python from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/8.0.html and also install using below command.

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

You can make settings for ENGINE in seeting.py as below.

```
    DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'user_data',
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
        'USER': 'mysql_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'OPTIONS': {
          'autocommit': True,
        },
    }
}
```

Then migrate using `manage.py migrate`
It worked for me I hope that same for you.

Answer (score 3):

Try to change the version of your `Django` and `mysqlclient`, I now use `mysqlclient==1.3.12` and `Django==2.0.5`.

Comment: I understand why people downvoted your answer, but at the same time, this was the only option for me. I was using 2.1, but unfortunately, updating our customer's database was not an option, so `Django==2.0.5` with `mysqlclient==1.4.2` were the solution for this.

Comment: I ran into the same problem. Python server version is 3.4 so I had to downgrade to django==2.0.13 and mysqlclient==1.3.14.

Answer (score 3):

```
from django.db.backends.mysql.base import DatabaseWrapper 
DatabaseWrapper.data_types['DateTimeField'] = 'datetime'
```

Answer (score 1):

> Django 2.1 does not support Mysql 5.5 yet.

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the documentation where you took this?

Comment: You can check docs from above commented link: `Django supports MySQL 5.5 and higher.` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/databases/#mysql-notes

Answer (score 0):

For `Django 3.2` I had to upgrade `mysql` from `5.5` to `5.7`.